# Updating text in GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

I am working on an amateur RPG and I have a problem with battle dynamics. When I press attack button I want the program to follow the `attack()` method in the program. In `actionPerformed()` method it should update the `JLabel`s. How I can update the `Jlabel`s when I press the button?

EDIT : I forgot to add `button.addActionListener(this);` Now it works!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.util.*;

public class Battle extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel label1, label2;
    private JButton button;
    private int playerHealth = 100;
    private int opponentHealth = 50;
    private int playerDamage, opponentDamage;

    public Battle(){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        label1 = new JLabel("You : " + Integer.toString(playerHealth));
        label2 = new JLabel("Opponent : " + Integer.toString(opponentHealth));
        button = new JButton("Attack!");
        panel.add(button);

        add(label1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(label2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        attack();
        label1.setText("You : " + Integer.toString(playerHealth));
        label2.setText("Opponent : " + Integer.toString(opponentHealth));
    }

    public void attack(){
        Random random = new Random();
        playerDamage = random.nextInt(10) + 5;
        opponentDamage = random.nextInt(5) + 5;
        playerHealth = playerHealth - opponentDamage;
        opponentHealth = opponentHealth - playerDamage;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Battle!");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Battle());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: `button.addActionListener(this);`

Comment: Oh! I knew I forgot something. Thank you very much.